# TouchDelegate applied to ListView only responds to click event

Tags: android, listview, delegates, touch

I'm trying to make a `ListView` the height of an individual item and then place it in the center of the parent view. This way the top and bottom of the list scroll to the center of the view. The problem arises when I apply a `TouchDelegate` to the `ListView` so the user can expand and move the list from above and below the actual `ListView`. I am able to click on the `ListView` via the `TouchDelegate` but I cannot swipe up & down or click and drag the list. Only tap it.

Do I have to create a `GestureDetector` for this or am I missing something simple?